# C Programm stops after function call

Tags: c, function

I'm new to C Programming and I've run into an issue. I'm trying to generate a poker deck, draw 7 random cards and check whether or not there are no pairs, one pair, two pairs, 3 of a kind, a fullhouse or 4 of a kind.

In principle my code works just as expected but after I call the function 'check_hand', the programm stops and I can't print anything.

Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {Hearts, Spaces, Clubs, Diamonds} suits;
typedef struct {
    suits suit;
    int pip;
} card;

// Generate the deck (no jokers, so 48 cards)
void generate_deck(card deck[48])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // loop through suits
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) // loop through pips
        {
            int deck_idx = i*12 + j;
            deck[deck_idx].suit = i; 
            deck[deck_idx].pip = j+1; // to start with value 1 (ace)
        }
    }
}

// generate random number in specified range
int rand_in_range(int lower, int upper)
{
    int i;
    int num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    return num;
}


// checks the hand for specified things
void check_hand(card hand[7], int count_array[])
{
    // array with a counter for each pip value
    int counter[12] = {0};

    // loop through hand
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        counter[hand[i].pip]++;
    }
    
    // counter variables that count the occurences of two, three and four of a kind
    int count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0;

    // count
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        switch (counter[i])
        {
            case 2: count2++; break;
            case 3: count3++; break;    
            case 4: count4++; break;
        }
    }

    /* Disclaimer: I deliberately chose those conditions to be not exclusive.
    That means that for example a fullhouse will also mean that one pair and
    a three of a kind will be counted. */

    // no pair (which also means no three of four of a kind)
    if (count2 == 0 && count3 == 0 && count4 == 0)
        count_array[0]++;
    // one pair
    if (count2 == 1)
        count_array[1]++;
    // two pair (also include three pairs)
    if (count2 >= 2)
        count_array[2]++;
    // three of a kind (also include multiple three of a kinds)
    if (count3 >= 1)
        count_array[3]++;
    // full house
    if (count3 == 1 & count2 >= 1)
        count_array[4]++;
    // four of a kind
    if (count4 >= 1)
        count_array[5]++;

    printf("Reached end of function 'check_hand'\n");
}

void print_counts(int count_array[6])
{   
    printf("Counts:\n");
    printf("No Pair:            %d\n", count_array[0]);
    printf("One Pair:           %d\n", count_array[1]);
    printf("Two Pair:           %d\n", count_array[2]);
    printf("Three of a kind:    %d\n", count_array[3]);
    printf("Fullhouse:          %d\n", count_array[4]);
    printf("Four of a kind:     %d\n", count_array[5]);
}



// main function
int main(void)
{
    // Generate deck
    card deck[48];
    generate_deck(deck);

    // draw seven random cards
    card hand[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        int idx = rand_in_range(0, 47);
        hand[i] = deck[idx];
        printf("Suit: %d,   Pip: %d\n", hand[i].suit, hand[i].pip);
    }

    /* each element of this array contains a counter for the following 
    things:
    Index 0            No Pair
    Index 1            One Pair
    Index 2            Two Pair
    Index 3            Three of a kind
    Index 4            Full House
    Index 5            Four of a kind
    */
    int count_array[6] = {0};
    check_hand(hand, count_array);
    print_counts(count_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `if (count3 == 1 && count2 >= 1)` instead of `if (count3 == 1 & count2 >= 1)`?

Comment: Have you tried to use a *debugger* to catch possible crashes? Or to just step through your code statement by statement?

Comment: Ìnsert `if (hand[i].pip >= 12 || hand[i].pip < 0)
    {
      printf("Bummer\n");
      exit(1);
    }
` right before `counter[hand[i].pip]++;` and see what happens.

Comment: Are you sure with the 48 cards? 1 (ace) - 10 are 10 cards + Jack + Queen + King are 13. 13 * 4 = 52.

Comment: Also, the way you're doing it, it seems you can draw 7 times the same card!

Comment: You are missing a `#include <stdlib.h>` but other than that it seems to work for me.  What output are you getting and what did you expect?  It's a boring game unless you set a seed with `srand()`.

Comment: @AllanWind the code is wrong, there is an out of bounds array index, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky op said  "after I call the function 'check_hand', the programm stops and I can't print anything." which is what I responded to.  I am not able to reproduce that.

Comment: @AllanWind out of bounds access => undefined behaviour => may work as expected, may crash, may get stuck etc.

Comment: @Jabberwocky which we agree on, of course.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks, that was the mistake, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Ok nevermind, I found the mistake. The pip value ranges from 1 to 13 but I'm using this value as an index of the counter array.

So

`counter[hand[i].pip]++;`

should be

`counter[hand[i].pip-1]++;`